# Applying ResourceDictionary Theme to a Simple MessageBox

Tags: c#, wpf, messagebox

Does anyone know this one?

I currently have an application with a bunch of user controls.  They are all themed with the "Dark Expressions" theme.  Anyways, when I call on a "MessageBox" using the common code:

```
MessageBox.Show("message", "title", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
```

It is using the generic windows theme.  Is it possible to create a themed message box very easily?  I have tried expending the MessageBox type with a user control, but I keep on getting the error "Cannot derive form sealed type "System.Windows.MessageBox"

The theme is defined using the ResourceDictionary way:

```
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="./Resources/Themes/ExpressionDark.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

So the gist of it is, I'd like my message box to look the same as my application; the cool and somber "dark expressions" theme.  Right now it looks out of place with the mildly amusing Win7 theme.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of custom message boxes available on the net like [this](http://blogsprajeesh.blogspot.com/2009/12/wpf-messagebox-custom-control.html) either you can use those after applying your theme to it or you can simply create your own not by deriving from the MessageBox class but by creating a custom control.

Comment: Agreed.  You need to roll your own.